# Visual Studio PowerShell AllowDrop Cannot be found on this object Error

Tags: winforms, powershell, visual-studio-2019

i have been working on a windows form, i have finally completed it and have built it, when i run the application there is an error with the form (there is no error when i am running it on VS)
please see error below, please note i loaded it into ISE so i could see the error

[image]

the code this is relating to is

```
This Is In FORM12.ps1

######################################## This is For Drag And Drop 
$handler = {
 $_.Data.GetFileDropList() | % {
   $listbox1.Items.Add($_)
  }
}
$listbox1.AllowDrop = $true
$listbox1.Add_DragEnter({$_.Effect = [Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects]::Copy})
$listbox1.Add_DragDrop($handler)
```

i don't understand what it means

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the full code?

Comment: @Wasif Hasan this is the full code for to the DragDrop command

Comment: Just tell me how $ListBox1 Listbox object was defined.

Comment: @WasifHasan i have added 2 more pictures does that help

Comment: if you don't find this line in your code: `$listbox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox` Add this before the line `$listbox1.AllowDrop = $True`

Comment: @WasifHasan that's great that has got rid of the errors but now i cant use the drag and drop

Comment: Ok, Let me write an answer.

Comment: Thank you @Wasif Hasan

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your script in an elevated environment or running as administrator, User Account Control (UAC) won't allow you to drag and drop on your program.

Run the program without elevated privileges then you will be allowed to drag and drop on your program.

Comment: I will give that a go, out of interest why can't it run as administrator

Comment: Error Message is still there